# Connection between 2 windows azure servers

Tags: azure, connectivity

I have 2 Windows Azure VMs. One is Database server and other is App server (hosting some .net application). I am trying to ping the Database server from App server but getting a request time out. I found that  [if load balancer is used we cannot ping the Azure VMs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity/).

My issue is I am not able to make sure weather these servers are connected or not. I found out a [similar kind of question](https://serverfault.com/questions/661201/two-virtual-machines-on-azure-can-connect-each-other-without-having-any-virtual) . But in my case i have turn off the firewalls of both VMs but still not able to connect.

Does anyone have idea about it?

Comment: Do you have any Network Security Groups (NSG) deployed on either the VM or the subnet?

Comment: Yes we have NSG deployed

Comment: Are you pinging to an internal IP address or the external IP address? You cannot ping to the external address, since ICMP isn't allowed through from the outside.

Comment: @PiyushJain, did you open the ports required for the connection on the NSGs? For example, if you use a database on a VM, you have to open the applicable database port on the NSG, so traffic can come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether the solution which worked for me is correct or not, but in my case the issue is with Public IP and Internal IP, i was trying to connect through public IP, when i tried a connection with internal IP it worked

Thanks for your responses

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Are both VMs in the same virtual network? In that case, by default you do not need NSG to allow communication between both servers. In the case you want to try to do a ping, you should allow the Windows Firewall rules like that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_azure_guide/2014/12/13/how-to-allow-ping-functionality-to-windows-azure-machines/

Otherwise, you can try to connect to the webserver with a browser from the database server, or try to connect to the database server from the webserver with a sql client.
Telnet may also help.